# How to position custom dashboard widgets on side column

Tags: widgets, dashboard

**My Question:**
Is it possible to add custom dashboard widgets in the right hand column instead of only on the left hands side?

I use `wp_add_dashboard_plugin( $widget_id, $widget_name, $callback, $control_callback = null )` to add the plugin code, but it doesn't have any options to allow you to set the position.

Any suggestions?

**My Comments:**
The Version 2.8 of WordPress suggests that it's possible, but I can't see anything in the code (/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php) that is related to this.

It seems only to add the dashboard plugin if its name is in the `$side_widgets` array, the contents of which are:
`array('dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard_secondary');`

My thoughts are that I'd have to directly modify `$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']` - but I'm not sure of the consequences of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right - it doesn't. Neither does the `wp_add_dashboard_widget` function. So just use the generic `add_meta_box` and indicate dashboard and placement:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_dashboard_setup_function' );
function my_dashboard_setup_function() {
    add_meta_box( 'my_dashboard_widget', 'My Widget Name', 'my_dashboard_widget_function', 'dashboard', 'side', 'high' );
}
function my_dashboard_widget_function() {
    // widget content goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's great. I'd wondered whether there'd be any additional setup beyond just using add_meta_box, but it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

> There currently **isn't** an easy API way to **pre-sort** the default
>   widgets, meaning your new widget will **always be at the bottom** of
>   the list.
>
> Below is an example hooking function that will try to put your widget
>   before the default ones. It does so by manually altering the internal
>   array of metaboxes (of which dashboard widgets are one type) and
>   putting your widget at the top of the list so it shows first.
>
> ```
> function example_add_dashboard_widgets() {
>     wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'example_dashboard_widget', 
>         'Example Dashboard Widget', 
>         'example_dashboard_widget_function' );
>
>     // Globalize the metaboxes array, this holds all the widgets for wp-admin    
>     global $wp_meta_boxes;
>
>     // Get the regular dashboard widgets array 
>     // (which has our new widget already but at the end)    
>     $normal_dashboard = $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'];
>
>     // Backup and delete our new dashbaord widget from the end of the array    
>     $example_widget_backup = array( 'example_dashboard_widget' => 
>         $normal_dashboard['example_dashboard_widget'] );
>     unset( $normal_dashboard['example_dashboard_widget'] );
>
>     // Merge the two arrays together so our widget is at the beginning   
>     $sorted_dashboard = array_merge( $example_widget_backup, $normal_dashboard );
>
>     // Save the sorted array back into the original metaboxes     
>     $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = $sorted_dashboard;
> }
> ```
>
> Unfortunately this only works for people who have never re-ordered
>   their widgets. Once a user has done so their existing preferences will
>   override this and they will have to move your widget to the top for it
>   to stay there.

Above content is quoted from Codex: [Forcing your widget to the top](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Forcing_your_widget_to_the_top)